# Azure Storage Explorer: server encountered internal error

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, localdb, azure-storage-emulator

I am getting the 'unable to retreive child resources" error when I click to expand the Emulator-default port=> tables node in Azure Storage Explorer(version 1.6.2). However the azure table storage emulator has been initialized and is running.

**Update:**
I deleted the `%appdata%/storageexplorer` folder(as suggested in my microsoft forums) and i face the same issue as before.

What am i missing?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was able to get the application working by

```
a. removing LocalDB database, 
b. deleting the localdb created mdf, ldf files, 
c. installing "SQL server Express" and manually creating the database that the Azure Storage explorer needed, and then configuring Azure Storage explorer to work with "SQL server Express"
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this issue, so it's hard to determine which caused this issue.

It would be better if you raise an issue to the Azure Storage Explorer team on [GitHub here](https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues). They would help for your issue.

And another way I can think is that you can uninstall the emulator and storage explorer, then reinstall the latest version.

Comment: I have already tried uninstalling and installing the emulator, storage explorer but without success.i will raise a ticket on github

Comment: I created a ticket here: https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues/1078

Answer (score 0):

At my case problem was because there are was more than one instance of MS SQL. Because of this instance wasn't correctly initialized. 
Our steps to fix issue

1. Remove created local DB
2. Run next command during initialization `AzureStorageEmulator.exe init /server .`

Please check [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator#storage-emulator-command-line-tool-reference) for more information about AzureStorageEmulator commands

Comment: I was able to resolve my issues with the above approach. It's worth checking out that full document at the link above.